# Adobe PDF links don't open in compiled Swift 5 running IOS 13.o, 13.1.2, and 13.2 beta but open in all IOS versions < 13.0

Tags: swift, hyperlink, ios13

I have made several pdfs containing hyperlinks using either Adobe Acrobat or Omnigraffle (exported as a pdf). Both of the compiled pdfs in my swift 5 app had links that could be opened by taps on my iPhone for all systems under IOS 13.0. Now none of the same pdf links work with iOS 13.0 13.1.2 or 13.2 beta from my compiled Swift 5 app by tapping or pressing the hyperlink. However they all work(ed) with an iOS < 13.

Interestingly I can put the same links into a button action within Swift 5 (or Swift 4) etc. and they will properly open the links. Seems to have something to do with absence of tap or press activation of the hyperlink or the hyperlink is in some way not allowed to perform.

Any help or confirmation of this issue will be appreciated. Thank you.

GT

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue for iOS 13 and iPadOS. There is a workaround:

1. Make your view controller class PDFViewDelegate.
2. After initializing your pdfView, point the delegate to the view controller:

   ```
   if #available(iOS 13.1, *) { // Necessary for keeping iOS<13 behavior
       pdfView.delegate = self
   }
   ```
3. Add this function:

   ```
   func pdfViewWillClick(onLink sender: PDFView, with url: URL) {
       if #available(iOS 13.1, *) {
           UIApplication.shared.open(url)
       }
   }
   ```

This will open all http and https links in Safari, but will not affect inner PDF bookmarks.